# SQL how to return a string when dbnull is found?

Tags: sql

To simplify the problem:

I have a select that can return at times NULL.

For example:

```
-- if the customer has no fax then NULL will be returned
select customerFax from customers
```

How can I check for this null, then return a string value instead of NULL, I need to display some friendly message in a report.

so if null - then return some string, else return the value from db...

I hope this is simple enough to understand - thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is typically done with the built in ISNULL function:

```
SELECT ISNULL(faxNumber, 'No fax') FROM customers
```

**Update: thanks to @gdn for pointing out that the message will get truncated if the message length > than the fields length, in which case you can solve it by Casting your original field to be as big as the message**

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(faxNumber AS VARCHAR(100), 'No fax specified at all, why didn''t you specify one before you asked me to display it for you? NEXT TIME MAYBE YOU SHOULD SPECIFY ONE.') 
FROM customers
```

Comment: I really love this answer. very simple to implement!

Comment: Note, this works because the string "no fax" will be shorter then the fax number. See my answer for why http://stackoverflow.com/a/9095812/27535

Comment: The coalesce answers are better than this one as ISNULL is not standard SQL and the question does not specify a specific DBMS.  While it will work with MS SQL Server it may or may not work with others

Comment: @DavidKnight true, but it is in MySQL, SQL Server and ORACLE (NVL) that's good enough for me, but surly to each his own.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CASE statement?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN customerFax IS NOT NULL THEN customerFax ELSE 'Friendly message' END FROM customers
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) like this

```
select IsNull(customerFax, 'There is no fax number specified, sorry.')  AS customerFax
from customers
```

or this

```
select COALESCE(customerFax, 'There is no fax number specified, sorry.')  AS customerFax
from customers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select coalesce(customerFax, 'replacement string') from customers
```

`coalesce` returns the first non null expression among its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If your customerFax column is, say, 11 characters long and your substitute message is longer (say 20), then ISNULL will truncate the substitute message. COALESCE and CASE won't

- ISNULL uses datatype of the 1st argument
- COALESCE and CASE use the highest precedence datatype/length